# flutter podfile is not created in ios folder

Tags: flutter

Previously, when creating a flutter project, a podfile was automatically created in the ios folder.

But when I create a new project today, the podfile is not created.

You can create it manually.

I want it to be auto-generated again.

Flutter Doctor seems to be fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The podfile should generate automatically, but if it fails, run the following commands From your IDE terminal to generate a podfile.

```
cd ios
pod init
```

Comment: I knew how to create them manually. I want it to be created automatically.

Comment: Did you try to create another project? Does it have the same issue?

Comment: Yes New projects have the same problem.

Comment: Then it's related to Cocoapods I think. Can you reinstall Cocoapods following the official documentation?